# How to create a singleton at the start of a grpc service?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, grpc

I have a service that should be created at the start of the application and I want to provide information about the service to the outside of the program.

My idea is a gRPC server (.NET Core 3.1) that creates the service at the start of the program and forwards the service to the gRPC controller using the default IoC container. My service should also be able to use other services using the default `IServiceProvider` (e.g. for logging).

My first approach was to create the service in `ConfigureServices` and passing the instance to `AddSingleton`. That did not work, because my service needs the `IServiceProvider` that hasn't been built in `ConfigureServices` yet.

I then found out that you can specify a factory that takes the service provider as an argument:

```
services.AddSingleton<IService>(serviceProvider => new Service(serviceProvider));
```

Now, my service gets access to all other services but it is only being created once a gRPC client requests information about the service.

Is there a way to instantly instantiate the service?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an instance of `ServiceProvider` at anytime inside `ConfigureServices` using `services.BuildServiceProvider()` and pass it to your `Service` singleton. Do note, however, that all services registered in the `IServiceCollection` **after** you create the `ServiceProvider` will not be accessible through the provider. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var service = new Service(sp);
    services.AddSingleton(service);

    // ...

    services.AddScoped<IOtherService, OtherServiceImplementation>();
    var otherService = sp.GetService<IOtherService>();
    // otherService == null
}
```

So... if you cannot wait with creating the singleton until access to it is requested, you should ensure that it's only created **after** all other necessary services have been registered.

Comment: This method actually works in my case but displays a warning that you should not call `BuildServiceProvider` in `ConfigureServices`. Therefore, this approach seems a bit tricky to me and probably isn't the optimal way to do it. Anyway, I'll accept your answer when nobody finds a better solution to this problem.

Comment: @NicoSchreiner and that warning is probably for the reason I mentioned - services registered later will not be available for the service provider. I don't think you'll find a much cleaner approach if you need to stick with your requirement about instantiating the service immediately.